# How to make a full black empty loading screen? That works all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I been looking for the perfect one but most of them I find on google have a problem of not showing a loading screen full screen sometimes they are able to but most of the time, usually on the edge they show a portion of the web page loading the contents behind the loading screen which is annoying how can I do this where all the time the full screen loading screen will always be full screen and then it shows the finished page. Example what I found most of the time on the web.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<style>

@font-face {
    font-family: raleway;
    src: url(/0/multimedia/fonts/raleway.ttf);
}


div#load_screen{
 background: black;
 opacity: 1;
 position: fixed;
    z-index:10;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1600px;
}
div#load_screen > div#loading{
 color: white;
 width:120px;
 height:24px;
 margin: 300px auto;
font-family: raleway;
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 320px) 
and (max-width : 736px){ 

div#load_screen{
 opacity: 1;
 position: fixed;
    z-index:10;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1600px;
}
div#load_screen > div#loading{
 color: white;
 width:185px;
 height:24px;
 margin: 125px auto;
font-size: 240%;
font-family: raleway;
}

}




</style>


</head>


<body>

<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
 var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
 document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
});

</script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/> <!--320-->
<div id="load_screen"><div id="loading">LOADING</div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then change CSS of that template and you'll get what you want.

Comment: Here's my example I find most of the time on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this properties:

```
div#load_screen{
    background: black;
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:10;
    top: 0px;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```